# Force all ASP.NET cache to expire

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Is there a method or something to force the expiration of all of the entries in the Cache collection of the HttpContext?

Comment: Restart the ASP.Net server :)

Comment: And what if its shared hosting ? you can't restart it i believe ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var enumerator = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();
Dictionary<string, object> cacheItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    cacheItems.Add(enumerator.Key.ToString(), enumerator.Value);

foreach (string key in cacheItems.Keys)
    HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove(key);
```

Comment: Why use a Dictionary to hold the cache items?  You only need to hold the keys; it would seem a List<string> would take care of it.

Comment: Good point. I was just thinking that I needed to keep that data around because you wouldn't be able to remove during a foreach on the enumerator.

Answer (score 0):

what about updating the cache to expire ?

```
protected void btnClearCache_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var enumerator = HttpRuntime.Cache.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(enumerator.Key.ToString(), enumerator.Value, 
            null, DateTime.Now , Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
}
```